# HTTP POST request with JSON payload from react app returns net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR(chrome)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, reactjs, ssl, puma

I have a react app that makes API call to the endpoint http://localhost:3020/schema/filter. Following is the payload that I am passing with the POST request.

```
let filterParams = {
            "filter": {
                "and": [{
                    "field": "name",
                    "operator": "LIKE",
                    "value": "Core"
                }, {
                    "field": "created_at",
                    "operator": "GREATER_THAN",
                    "value": "05/26/2017"
                }, {
                    "field": "created_at",
                    "operator": "LESS_THAN",
                    "value": "07/02/2017"
                }]
            }
        }

let response = await apiService.post('https://localhost:3020/schema/filter', filterParams)
```

API SERVER is rails app with puma server.
Server console responds with

> 2017-07-04 12:04:05 +0545: HTTP parse error, malformed request ():
> #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.

API SERVER is configured to respond to the JSON payload. Whenever I try to POST request with the payload , the browser responds with

> `OPTIONS https://localhost:3020/schema/filter net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in the browser console in chrome.

Similarly, safari console returns

> `Fetch API cannot load https://localhost:3020/schema/filter. An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.`

Seems like I am having trouble with SSL or certificates. I tried deleting browser caches, cookies and certificate itself. Still no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using https or not? Because the first link says plain http while the others use https. Given that https results in a SSL protocol error - are you sure that there is even https enabled and configured on port 3020? *malformed request* also suggests that it is actually expecting a HTTP request and is confused by the TLS ClientHello (start of SSL handshake) it gets from the client instead. Thus, try `http://` instead of `https://` in your URL's.

Comment: Yeah, missed that point totally. I was using `https` instead of `http`. Thank you for saving my. Worked like a charm . :)

Answer (score 4):

This is an error because your service is posting to `https://localhost` but your rails server is MOST LIKELY not running with https.

If your react app, you should do something like:

```js
var apiBase = process.env === 'PRODUCTION' ? 
    'https://www.productionapp.com/' : 'http://localhost:3000/'

let response = await apiService.post(apiBase + '/schema/filter', filterParams)
```