# Fetch data from api in createContext using Fetch api in React doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, react-context

I have an existing `context` for products. Where initially I used some mock data as shown below `STORE_DATA` to render the components. Now I need to replace that mock data and connect to a `Node.js` api which is available on my `local port` (created the api I after I created the `react-app`).

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import STORE_DATA from '../shop';

export const ProductsContext = createContext();

const ProductsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [products] = useState(STORE_DATA);

return (
  <ProductsContext.Provider value={{ products }}>
    {
      children
    }
  </ProductsContext.Provider>
 );
}

export default ProductsContextProvider;
```

Just created a `helper.js` file witht he following to fetch the data:

```
 import {useEffect} from "react";


const fetchData = () => {
    return fetch("https://localhost:8081/products") <<tested on postman and works fine.
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => console.log('Fetching Data:',data));
}
```

How to replace the mock data on the `context` file and use this `fetchData()` using `useEffect` within the `context`? What code should change?

Tried the following, but didn't work, can't even print the `console.log`:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchData } from '../helpers';

export const ProductsContext = createContext();

const ProductsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(fetchData());
    }, []);

  return (
    <ProductsContext.Provider value={{ products }}>
      {
        children
      }
    </ProductsContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default ProductsContextProvider;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that it was returning the following error ([explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44898356/1108500)):

`net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR (on chrome)`

Solution: Use `http://` instead of `https://` in the URL's in the following code:

```
const fetchData = () => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8081/products") 
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => console.log('Fetching Data:',data));
}
```